# Any way to show wild animal health?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

Is there a way (console command or config option) to see how much health a wild animal has? An example is the Trilobytes. I'll start hitting them, and they'll start moving, and the music will start playing, but there are no blood effects or impact noises. They do die after repeated hits.

Is there some sort of indicator to confirm a hit if the blood and impact noises don't appear?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like there is a way to measure how much health an animal has, other than to estimate. I know on the wiki, it will say it takes around 50 arrows to take down a T Rex, and that seems to be the best way to measure it.

ARK currently does not have a hit indicator system, but many people have suggested it and it might just happen soon.

For reference, here is a wiki list of all of the dinosaurs and you can find a "measure" of their health there: [ARK Dinosaurs](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Dinosaurs)

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime there is the item "[Magnifying Glass](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Magnifying_Glass)", that allows you to see the health of a wild creature. You have to be very close, though, so it's not usefull for large carnivores as a rex ;)

There's also a mod that shows the health and torpor of all creatures: [Healthbars & Torporbars V2](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=642284892)